# How can we generate unique links in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to generate a unique link for the user when he click on the generate link button.How can I write the onclick function for generating unique links using javascript in angularjs?

Comment: what do you mean by `unique links`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to generate random strings and links:

```
$scope.randomString = function(length) { 
  var chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  var result = '';
  for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) {
    result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: You can use above function to create a random link.